# Toy Camera filter for Android Image Processing

Tags: android, image-processing

I have a small Android app I am building to apply filters/effects on a picture taken from the camera or from the image gallery. So far I have blur, sepia, emboss, b&w, contrast, etc. However, the one I am looking for seems to be hard to find using google. I would like to apply the toy camera effect as well. I see a lot of Android apps doing this, but I can't find the algorithm to implement to Android.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: I would think that going through code of some open source Java image processing libraries might be a good start. As far as I understand your question, it really comes down to learning the image processing part, not the Android part.

Comment: Yes, i am a android developer, so android and java are ok to me, i just need to understand how this toy cam works.

Comment: The "toy camera" effect is usually a combination of other adjustments. In my copy of Aperture, the "toy camera" preset just cranks up the vibrancy and lightens the shadows. Experiment a bit, see what gives you the result you want (and consider asking a similar question on [photo.SE](http://photo.stackexchange.com/) as this is mostly an image editing question, not so much a programming one).

Comment: Can you post a link to something that shows the "toy camera" effect? I can give you more info once I see what you mean.

Comment: Here you can find some images with Toy Camera effect http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/03/10/uncovering-toy-cameras-and-polaroid-vintage-effects/

Answer (score 1):

As @You said above the toy camera effect is more than likely a number of adjustments. In my experience you should look into adding a vignette (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vignetting) and emulating E6/C41 cross processing. Cross-processing can be easily achieved by manipulating the individual RGB channel such as the curves shown here http://www.reynsphoto.com/articles/Post_Processing/html/Digital_cross-processing_C-41_as_E-6.php. Furthermore, you can add a slight yellow tint.

hope this helps